# Php response displays in browser instead of firing the ajax callback

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback

I've spent some time looking on SO for an answer to this and have found some related issues, but nothing quite like mine...as usual....

I've got a fairly simple php/jquery ajax registration page that is working right up until the ajax callback. What I mean is the form data is passing to php and inserting into the db but when the php response is supposed to come back all that happens is the response displays in the browser. I've followed the logs, checked fiddler, re-written the code with/without json, and anothing seems to change. The odd thing is I have another form on a different page that is set up exactly the same way and everything works there perfectly. The only difference I can find between the two pages is the Request Headers of the php file. The one that works accepts json and the one the other one doesn't, but I have no idea if that means anything . . . I'm kind of grabbing for anything at this point.

So, without further delay, here is my code. Any thoughts/input are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" /> 
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" href="IEjoin.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
        <div id="headline">
            <h1>Create your account</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <form id="register" action="form.php" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li id="first_name">
                        <input name="fname" type="text" value="" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="30">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="last_name">
                        <input name="lname" type="text" value="" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="30">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="email_address">
                        <input name="email" type="text" value="" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="60">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="uname">
                        <input name="username" type="text" value="" id="username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15">
                        <div class="error"></div>   
                    </li>
                    <li id="pword">
                        <input name="password" type="password" value="" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="gender_select">
                        <select id="gender" name="gender">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select your gender</option>
                            <option value="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female">Female</option>
                            <option value="unspecified">Unspecified</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li id="submit_button">
                        <button id="register_button" class="register_button_disabled">Create Account</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
            <script> $('input[placeholder]').placeholder();</script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {



function validateEmail(email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test(email);
}
function submitButton() {
    if (($("#first_name").hasClass("good")) && ($("#email_address").hasClass("good")) && ($("#uname").hasClass("good")) && ($("#pword").hasClass("good")) ){
        $("#register_button").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#register_button").removeClass("register_button_disabled").addClass("register_button");
    } else {
        $("#register_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#register_button").removeClass("register_button").addClass("register_button_disabled");
    }
}
$("body").mousedown(submitButton);
$("body").keyup(submitButton);
$("body").hover(submitButton);
$("body").mouseover(submitButton);
$("#fname").keydown(function(){
    $("#first_name").removeClass("required");
    $("#first_name div").html("");
});
$("#fname").bind ("keyup mousedown",function(){
    if(this.value===""){
        $("#first_name").removeClass("good").addClass("wait");
    } else {
        $("#first_name").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }       
});
$("#fname").blur(function(){
    if(this.value===""){
        $("#first_name").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
        $("#first_name div").html("Please enter your first name");
    } else {
        $("#first_name").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }       
});
$("#email").keydown(function(){
    $("#email_address").removeClass("required");
    $("#email_address div").html("");
});
$("#email").bind ("keyup mousedown",function(){
    var email = this.value;
    var emailLength = email.length;
    if (emailLength<=4){
        $("#email_address").removeClass("good").addClass("wait");
    } else {
        $("#email_address").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }       
});
$("#email").blur(function(){
    var email = this.value;
    var emailLength = email.length;
    if ((emailLength<=4) || (!validateEmail(this.value))) {
            $("#email_address").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
        $("#email_address div").html("Please use a valid email address");
    } else if (emailLength>=3){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "Check.php",
            data: "email="+email,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { 

                if (data.status === "success") {
                    $("#email_address").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                    $("#email_address div").html("Sorry, that email is already used");}
                else {
                    $("#email_address").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");  
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
         $("#email_address").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }
});
$("#username").keydown(function(){
    var un = this.value;
    var unLength = un.length;
    if(unLength<3){
        $("#uname").removeClass("good").addClass("wait");
    } else {
        $("#uname").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }       
});
$("#username").bind ("keyup mousedown",function(){
    $("#uname").removeClass("required");
    $("#uname div").html("");
});
$("#username").blur(function(){
    var un = this.value;
    var unLength = un.length;
    if(unLength<3){
        $("#uname").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
        $("#uname div").html("Please use at least 3 characters");
    } else if (unLength>=3){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "check.php",
            data: "username="+un,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { 

                if (data.status === "success") {
                    $("#uname").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                    $("#uname div").html("Sorry, that username is taken");
                } else {
                    $("#uname").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");  
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#uname").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }
});
$("#password").keydown(function(){
    var pw = this.value;
    var pwLength = pw.length;
    if(pwLength<=5){
        $("#pword").removeClass("good").addClass("wait");
    } else {
        $("#pword").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }       
});
$("#password").bind ("keyup mousedown",function(){
    $("#pword").removeClass("required");
    $("#pword div").html("");
});
$("#password").blur(function(){
    var pw = this.value;
    var pwLength = pw.length;
    if(pw===""){
        $("#pword").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
        $("#pword div").html("Please enter a password");
    }
    if(pwLength<=5){
        $("#pword").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
        $("#pword div").html("Please use at least 6 characters");
    } else {
        $("#pword").removeClass("wait").addClass("good");
    }
});

$("#button").click(function(e) {


    e.preventDefault();     

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "form.php",
        data: $('#register').serialize(),
        success: function(data) { 
            if (data === "fname") {
                $("#first_name").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                $("#first_name div").html("Please enter your first name"); 

            } else if (data === "email") {
                $("#email_address").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                $("#email_address div").html("Please use a valid email address");

            } else if (data === "email2") {
                $("#email_address").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                $("#email_address div").html("Sorry, that email is already used");

            } else if (data === "username") {
                $("#uname").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                $("#uname div").html("Please use at least 3 characters");

            } else if (data === "username2") {
                $("#uname").removeClass("good").addClass("required");
                $("#uname div").html("Sorry, that username is taken");

            } else {
                window.location.href = "http://site.com";

        },
        error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
        } 
    });             
    return false;

});
```

});

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name  

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);

//validate inputs
$emailpull = "SELECT email FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email'";
$emailresult=mysql_query($emailpull);
$emailnum=mysql_num_rows($emailresult);

$emailReg = "/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/";

$unpull = "SELECT username FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$unresult=mysql_query($unpull);
$unnum=mysql_num_rows($unresult);

if ($fname == "") {  
$response = "fname";

} elseif ($email == "") {
$response = 'email';

} elseif (!preg_match($emailReg, $email)) {
$response = 'email';

} elseif ($emailnum > 0) {
$response = 'email2';

} elseif (strlen($username)<3) {
$response = 'username'; 

} elseif ($unnum > 0) {
$response = 'username2';

} elseif (strlen($password)<6) {
$response = 'password';

} else {

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(fname,lname,email,username,password,gender)VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$username','$password','$gender')";
}

$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
$response = "success";

// send message back 
echo $response;

?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: I usually find it helps to remove unecessary code until you're able to reproduce the problem. This also helps people answer the question. One question. The button has id "register_button" but the javascript references "button". Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click handler for #button has this line which may be the culprit:

```
window.location.href = "http://crushonit.com";
```

This will redirect to that page when the form has no validation errors.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jim. You were right on with your comment above about the button being named incorrectly. Genius! I had been skipping over that all day because it was "working" when I clicked the button . . . now it makes total sense what they callback methods weren't being called, since I wasn't even activating that button! Odd that the data was still being transmitted though.

Comment: Oh yeah, you were also on to something about the redirect. It's my intention for a redirect to work when I get a "success" message. That still isn't working though and it has something to do with using e.preventDefault() and return false correctly. But I guess that is for another day . . . thank you for your input. Very helpful!